# Subset of combinations of an array- AS3

Tags: java, arrays, actionscript-3, subset

Say that I have an array [0,1,2,3] and a parameter 2 as input

I want the output to be

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 0
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 0
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 0
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

The parameter's length determines the number of combinations in each tuple, while the array is used to generate the numbers.

Is there a quick way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I don't know, but in first, I have created `combinations` and `permutations`, and after sometime, I have created utility method for your task.

```
var subsetTest:Array = [];
subsetFill([0, 1, 2], [], subsetTest, 2);
prettyPrint(subsetTest);

private function subsetFill(values:Array, cursor:Array, result:Array, length:uint):void {
    if (cursor.length > length) {
        return;
    }
    if (cursor.length == length) {
        result.push(cursor.slice());
    }

    var i:uint, len:uint = values.length;

    for (i; i < len; ++i) {
        cursor.push(values[i]);
        subsetFill(values, cursor.slice(), result, length);
        cursor.length = cursor.length - 1;
    }
}

//Auxiliary method for tracing 
private function prettyPrint(list:Array):void {
    var i:uint, len:uint = list.length;

    for (i; i < len; ++i) {
        trace(list[i]);
    }
}
```

And a result:

```
[trace] 0,0
[trace] 0,1
[trace] 0,2
[trace] 1,0
[trace] 1,1
[trace] 1,2
[trace] 2,0
[trace] 2,1
[trace] 2,2
```

If someone interested, I also could share `combinations` and `permutations` functions ;)

Comment: Hi, is there any way to make this implementation go faster? I would like to go upto length 10, but in that case its too computationally intensive. I there some way to make escaping more efficient when length>needed length. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: 10? Uh-oh, It's many cycles and of cause It's very intensive... If your data isn't dynamic enough, you could precompute value only once with provided algorithm, or you could move this algorithm to the [Worker](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html)

Comment: Thank you! The worker idea looks interesting..Will try it! Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to get your opinion about this. Do you think trying to use 4 nested loops to generate a similar list would be faster than the proposed solution.

Comment: Maybe, iterations is better and faster than recursion, but recursion provides readable and compact solutions. You should do small benchmark and share your results. Just before computation store time and subtract result after operation: `var time: int = getTimer(); //do computation; trace("Time: " + (getTimer() - time));`

Comment: Would it even work. I am stuck how to proceed after this..

    `private function anotherFill(arr:Array,length:int)
  {
   for(var i:uint=0; i<length;i++){
    for(var j:uint=i;j<length;j++){
     for(var k:uint=j;k<length;k++){
 
     }
    }
   }
  }`

Comment: If you stuck, so don't go with it. You have working algorithm, intensive task, and workers. I would go with Workers.

Comment: Thanks! I will post benchmarks if I implement the for loop thing.

Answer (score 0):

Three for cycles:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < to_do.length; i++) {
    for (var k:int = 0; k < to_do[i];k++){
        new_array.push(new Array());
        for (var j:int = 0; j < another_array.length; j++) {
            new_array[k].push(another_array[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

This should get the job done.

Comment: Thanks. But the output is not what I expect. It returns an array with 8 arrays with each having different combinations of 0 1 2 and 3.

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear. What I want is to find all combinations of another_array [0,1,2,3] which is limited by the length of to_do (2).